# Azure Devops x On-Premises

Tags: azure, firewall

Do I need to allow Azure DevOps access to the On-Premises environment? According to the document at "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url? view = azure-devops, " on "Inbound connections" connections are made from the 191.235.226.0/24 (Brazil South) network, but we are receiving connections to our IPs 40.65.126.175, 40.117.36.92 and 52.152.147.38.

And the IPs are changed with each access making it impossible to restrict access.

Know someone who can answer?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?
If your goal is to run build agents to execute pipelines on premises, then you don't have to allow inbound access. Build agents will query Azure DevOps for any new jobs, so the connections are actually outbound.